# Can I setup caching properties in the web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, .net-4.0

Specifically for .NET 4.0, I will be using the System.Runtime.Caching namespace.  Let's say all my methods will use sliding expiration with a duration of 20 minutes.  Is it possible to place this in a config file?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: You could set a property/value in your AppSettings that you can retrieve using "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="slidingExpirationInMinutes" value="20" />
</appSettings>
```

You can then grab this value and turn into an integer:

```
int cacheValue;
string cacheValueAsString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["slidingExpirationInMinutes"];
if(int.TryParse(cacheValueAsString, out cacheValue)
{
   //Set the value here
}
else
{
   //Fallback to default?
}
```

I assume you know how to set the sliding value through programatic means?